# Editing Arabic-English files in Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, arabic

I'm writing latex documents with Arabic as a primary language and some mathematical symbols. My editor of choice is emacs, but I'm having a very difficult time in typing this document up due to symbols mixing/not showing up properly. To give an example:

```
 يمكنناتمثيل مجموعةٍ بعدد من الطُرق:
\begin{enumerate}
\item   :كتابة عناصرها داخل اقواس متعرّجة، مثلاً: $\set{a, b, c}$
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

Notice the positions of the backslashes for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing for Latex processing will be the logical order, not the display order, so you can just ignore the unexpected display, although proof reading will be complicated by this issue.

The confusion here is caused by the fact that backslash is defined with "OTHER NEUTRALS" as its BiDi property in the Unicode spec. This means it is neither RTL nor LTR, so its grouping depends on the surrounding text. As it is appearing on the boundary between RTL and LTR text, the result is not what you might expect, though your expectation seems reasonable given the whitespace between the two blocks, so this could be a bug in Emacs BiDi handling.  If you report this as an Emacs bug, I guess Eli Zaretskii will be able to clarify whether this is a bug in Emacs or an unexpected consequence of strict Unicode BiDi algorithm compliance.